# How to create Template for email alerts in SP2010?

Tags: 2010, list, email, email-templates

I need to create a template for sending email alerts in such a way that I can select columns for individual lists for the content to be displayed in the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly how to answer based on the small amount of detail you have provided, but would a SharePoint Designer workflow serve the purpose? With that, you can set the text to whatever you'd like as well as include column values.

Comment: Thats right! Here is more information: We have many lists on our SharePoint site. Each list requires different columns to be displayed in alert mails. But manually doing it is cumbersome process. What we need is way to select columns that are required in alert mails. Is this possible?

Comment: Again, it all depends on what you are trying to do. It sounds like you're looking for one answer to multiple situations. In some cases, SPD workflows may well be a good solution.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for one template for multiple list.You said 'SPD workflows may well be a good solution.'... do you have a link for it?

Comment: You'd create a different workflow for each list or type of list from the sounds of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can Create customtemplate for each type of library and can customize no of fields to be include/exclude.

Good example to go with [CustomAlertTemplate](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sharepointadmin/thread/473cac18-7692-4a20-ab35-3120c67ac40c).